# how to set more fine grained playback rate on youtube video

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I'm creating a custom player that supports multiple providers (youtube, vimeo, direct videos...). And I noticed that when I use `setPlaybackRate()`, with the Youtube API it only allows for values one specific numbers like `0.25` `0.5` `0.75` `1`... but it just ignores values like `0.85` `0.72` `1.15`. Why is that? Using the HTML5 video tag on the browser those values are happly accepted (also, I have a browser extension that works on youtube, with the extension I can have direct access to the video tag, and there I can use those custom playback rates).

There is any reason to don't accept those numbers on the iframe api? My player is targetted for musicians, so the playback rate is one pretty important feature for me to have fine control over.

Sorry this question is a bit off StackOverflow kinds of questions, but I didn't know anywhere else to ask for it.

Comment: Because those are the only values it supports?

Comment: @DaveNewton that doesn't make sense, since the the iframe player that I'm using is using a <video> tag under the hood (I can see by inspecting it), if the <video> tag supports those playback rates (if I use my browser I can manually do that by javascript on the console), it just that the youtube iframe api is imposing those limits, which doens't make sense to me